# rsync password mismatch although it is a scp copy

Tags: rsync

The following command results in auth fail:

```
sudo rsync -zvrtp db_backup_test/* rsync_backup@172.28.15.15::backupmysql --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.secrets --port=873

@ERROR: auth failed on module backupmysql
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1516) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Server log shows:
[image: server error log]

The problem is secret file on server side is the one copied from the client. There is no way it has any mis-spelling.

This is rsyncd.conf:

```
[backupmysql]
path = /data/mysql/backup
auth users = rsync_backup
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
[other]
path = /data/other/backup
auth users = rsync_backup
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

This is rsyncd.secrets (scp from client):

```
rsync_backup:123456
```

without specifying password file, when password is prompted, I could manually input password, and then it does not have auth problem.

Comment: finally found the reason. in rsync client, password file should contain only password, not `username:herpassword`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tiina found the reason. :

In rsync client, password file should contain **only password**, 
**not** `username:herpassword`

but just `herpassword`

Posted like an answer because is right